# automake install target prior to make check

Tags: autoconf, automake

How can I get automake to install one of the libraries prior to executing the check scripts?

The project builds a mock testing library for one of the libraries we dynamically load (via a call to `dlopen`). The problem is that we can't override our library path for testing since there are still a number of other libraries which must be loaded (these are installed by other components not directly compiled by this makefile).

It'd save me a lot of work if I could simply cause some library to be installed prior to the check scripts being run. If I have to put it in a separate makefile and call that first, then fine, no problem. Essentially I just need running `make check` to do the right thing.

Comment: This behaviour would make `make check` do very much the wrong thing. Your package's `make check` would behave differently to almost every other `make check`. From http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html#Standard-Targets : "you should write the self-tests so that they work when the program is built but not installed."

Comment: It's just not possible for this product. It __needs__ a staging are to combine several dependent projects.

Answer (score 4):

The `make check` target is supposed to test the package before its installation. Automake offers no way around that.  The idea is that if `make check` fails, you may decide not to install the package at all.  (Also, if you hack your rules in some way to install during `make check`, you will probably break `make distcheck`.)

The usual way to use local libraries before installed libraries is to prepend `.:` to the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` during your tests.  Using `libtool` to build your local libraries and link to them will handle all these uportable details for you: the executables `libtool` outputs in the build tree are scripts that sets these variables before calling the right exectutable (hidden elsewhere), to ensure they use the local libraries.

Another solution, if you still want to perform tests after installation, is not to use `make check` but `make installcheck`.  The `make installcheck` is expected to be run only after the user have run `make install`.  You would have to write your own `installcheck-local` rule.

Comment: We don't use "make install" as our final package. We use it to prepare a further package which can be installed. `libtool` also fails to work when there are multiple automake projects and global libraries with different version dependencies.

Comment: For similar reasons, relating to versions, we cannot use LD_LIBRARY_PATH to load these libraries, we need a more limited path scope (at the moment we support just one -- but obviously an answer would be to support more).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any official/proper way, but the following appears to work. Add a new dependency to `check` and use the install libraries target, but overriding which libraries are installed. For example:

```
check_dummy: lib_LTLIBRARIES = libdummy.la
check_dummy: install-libLTLIBRARIES
check: check_dummy
```

This GNU Make specific I believe.